# Fetch column value with special characters from oracle database

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have a table in Oracle DB, which may contains values that have special characters like "&" in them.

For E.g.

```
ID      Item_Description
1        Book & Marker
2        Pen & Paper
3        Pencil
4        Marker
```

I have a stored procedure, where item description is passed as parameter. In the SP, I have to query the table to get records matching the parameter.

```
select * from table where item_description = v_desc;
```

When i run this stored procedure, with parameter value as "Book & Marker", no records are returned by the procedure.

Is this because of the special character? Because when I tried to change column value to "Book and Marker" and passed the same in the parameter value, record was found and returned by the stored procedure. How can this be handled with the special character?

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you posted procedure you use, as well as the way you're calling it. Meanwhile, here's what might be going on.

Test case: table and **function** (it is easier to return something from a function than a procedure):

```
SQL> select * from marker;

        ID ITEM_DESCRIPT
---------- -------------
         1 Book & Marker
         2 Pen & Paper
         3 Pencil
         4 Marker

SQL> create or replace function f_marker (v_desc in marker.item_description%type)
  2    return marker.id%type
  3  as
  4    retval marker.id%type;
  5  begin
  6    select m.id
  7      into retval
  8      from marker m
  9      where m.item_description = v_desc;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Testing: simple case first:

```
SQL> select f_marker('Pencil') result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
         3
```

Now, calling the same function for `Book & Marker`: my tool (SQL*Plus) is expecting me to enter value for the substitution variable named `marker`; that's certainly not what I wanted.

```
SQL> select f_marker('Book & Marker') result from dual;
Enter value for marker:

    RESULT
----------
```

Therefore, I'll use `set define off` which treats `&` as any other character:

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> select f_marker('Book & Marker') result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Works OK now.

---

If that doesn't help, as I said - post your test case so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We did try set define off. It works in the query. However when we use it in the stored procedure, we get the following error:  Error(22,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 Error(22,9): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: You're welcome. To repeat: "as I said - post your test case so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded."